# How can you check how much of a bcache cache is currently in use?

Tags: statistics, bcache

I've got a setup that includes a bcache cache device serving multiple backing devices. I would like to know how much of it is currently in use because bcache only caches certain kinds of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stats for the cache device of a certain bcache cache set can be queried using `/sys/fs/bcache/$CSET_UUID/cache0/priority_stats`.
Among other information, it contains the `unused` field.